# Deleting table in EF c#, what's my table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datatable

I'm trying to delete a table in EF that contains a bunch of object instances and their properties, but the code isn't working. What I have so far is:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string name;
    public List<string> type;
    public List<string> def;
    public HashSet<string> syns;
    public HashSet<string> generator_list = new HashSet<string>();
    public List<Point> related_items2 = new List<Point>();
}
```

And the EF code looks like

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base()
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Item> items_db { get; set; }
}
```

And then there is the actual code:

```
    using (var ctx = new Context())
    {
        ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [items_db]");
    }
```

But the error I'm getting is `Cannot find the object items_db because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

A related question is that the reason I'm deleting it in the first place is because I've been adding the same objects to it again and again, but when I try to retrieve the objects, all the properties are 0 or null except for the index property. Am I doing something wrong here too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You table name would be `Items`, like the class name in plural.

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
   ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE Items");
}
```

What also should work to remove it directly over the `DbSet`:

```
using (var ctx = new Context())
{
   IQueryable<Item> allItems = ctx.items_db;
   ctx.items_db.RemoveRange(allItems);
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

This would actually only remove all the items but not reset the auto increment counter etc.

Comment: Thanks, it works great, but something weird is happening. I save the data, and when I retrieve it, it's all there, but when I restart the program and try retrieving the data, I get a list with the elements, but all their property values are NULL?! Do you know why that is? Thanks

Comment: With the code above the data gets deleted from the table. Do you have any initializer which adds data on app start or somewhere different? Do you mean the Items table or another one? This can have several causes and I don't think it's related to the deletion here.

Comment: No, I ran the deletion just once (then commented it out), and restarted the program, made sure there wasn't any more data. Then I added data to the table, and I retrieved it to check the content, and everything checked out, so I closed the program, restarted it, tried retrieving the data again, but this time, all the properties were null. It's like it wasn't actually saving the data in the first place, just reading it...?

Comment: @Daws has may answer your question. Otherwise it maybe a problem with saving the data to the database, not with reading or deleting them. If the other answer doesn't help you, you may ask another question on StackOverflow and describe the code you have and what exactly it does wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to implement his suggestions, but when I do, I get the error that "the Context context model has changed"... how can I just totally remove the db and start from a clean slate with Daws recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your related question, the reason all the fields are 0 or null is because Entity Framework will only map database columns to properties, not fields. Also, EF won't store a list of strings on your entity class. One option is creating a new entity for each of the lists.

Try something like this (you will need to create entity classes for each of ItemType, Def, Syn, Generator, and Point):

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ItemType> Types { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Def> Definitions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Syn> Syns { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Generator> GeneratorList { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Point> RelatedItems { get; set; }
}
```

The new entity classes might look something like this:

```
public class ItemType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that makes sense, but sorry for this dumb question, but where would I put the code and what would the code be to make an entity class for ItemType, for example?

Comment: The code for the new entities would be very similar to the Item class. You could start with just defining two properties: an int for the Id and a string for the value. It would basically be a wrapper for a string with the addition of an Id property.

Comment: Ok, and when I retrieve the data, do I have to type something different since it looks like the data is split across different tables? And I made the changes and I get an error that "the model backing the Context context has changed". What can I do to start the db with a clean slate?

Comment: You can still access the data from the main Item table ('item.Types' would give you the list of types). To update your model run 'add-migration ItemUpdate' followed by 'update-database' from the package manager console.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but I get this error? `No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly`

Comment: Ok, I ran a few other commands and then yours, and they ran without error, but can you just tell me how I can totally start over the db? I keep getting other errors and I feel it'll be more productive if I can start over.

Comment: Do you have any important data in your DB? If not, you should be able to drop your database and run 'update-database' to recreate it. Although, if the other commands were successful, this won't change too much.